Meson can't find libm while cross-compiling
I've written a Meson build script to cross-compile a project.
Right now I have the full thing running but am having trouble finding libm "the proper way".
My toolchain is arm-none-eabi and it's installed to /usr/arm-none-eabi. I can see that libm is available there as /usr/arm-non-eabi/libm.a. If I add -lm to my link_args in the executable Meson will find and compile it just fine. However using the find_library function it refuses to find this same library.
math_dep = declare_dependency(
    dependencies: cc.find_library(
        'm',
        required: true,
    )
)

meson.build:112:21: ERROR: C shared or static library 'm' not found

In the Meson log I can see that it does search in the right directory.
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/arm-none-eabi/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/arm-none-eabi/usr/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/:/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/:/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/:/usr/arm-none-eabi/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/14.1.0/:/usr/arm-none-eabi/usr/lib/

The proper directory in that list being third to last.
$ ls /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib | grep "libm.a"
libm.a

Why is Meson failing to find this dependency while it is available and I can link to it just fine if I manually specify it to the linker?

Set Meson aside. Write a hello world type program that uses a function from the math library. Compile and link by typing compilation commands in the terminal window. No make, cmake, ninja, meson or any of these monstrosities. Does it work?

Obviously yes that works. The whole problem is that I can't get it to work with Meson. I'm not asking how to link to the math library in general but how to do it with Meson, properly (so not manually specifying the linker flag).
Also what's that "could be an AI" statement about?

I don't know the first thing about Meson but it seems to me that declare_dependency is the wrong tool for the jib. Dependencies are external/third-party packages. libm.a is packaged with your compiler. There is no dependency to speak of. You need an additional compiler argument. You probably shouldn't need to specify a directory for it, it's in the same place as all the required libraries like libc. If your build can find libc, it can find libm.

@PureTryOut You'll need to give us more information. Show us a Minimal Reproducible Example in which libm.a is not
found by cc.find_library() but the target is successfully linked with -lm put in the link_args. This MRE should include the Meson cross file as well aa the
meson.build. It's not that hard to imagine why cc.find_library() might not work, but if didn't it's obscure how you successfully link something with -lm in the link_args.
